# C#: Edit Outlook 2010 nickname cache

Tags: c#, autocomplete, outlook

I want to write a program that can edit the nickname cache of Outlook 2010. In detail I want to delete single contacts in the nickname cache.

I've already searched for a long time for a solution and I've found many ideas but no idea leads to the solution.

I already get the Autocomplete-Stream but I can't parse this byte-Array because I don't know the encoding/structure of this stream.

Has someone a idea how I can solve my problem?

Thank you!

Best regards
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Nickname cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625288.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN which describes all possible ways for editing nickname caches.

For Outlook 2007, the autocomplete stream is stored in a file with the same name as the profile and an extension of .nk2. For example, if the default profile of "outlook" is used, the file will be called "outlook.nk2". The .nk2 file is stored in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook.

**Outlook 2010 and later**

Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013 reads the autocomplete stream from a message in the Associated Contents table of the Inbox of the mail account’s delivery store. This hidden message has a message class and subject of IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete. The autocomplete stream is stored on this message in the PR_ROAMING_BINARYSTREAM property (PidTagRoamingBinary Canonical Property). The autocomplete data may be temporarily cached in an autocomplete .dat file located in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\RoamCache. However, the .dat file is only a cache and is not used to write back to the delivery store when the user exits Outlook 2010 and later.

On the page mentioned you can also find recommendation for editing the cache programmatically:

- Never partially modify the autocomplete stream. The supported interaction is to 1) read the entire autocomplete stream into memory, 2) modify the memory structure, and 3) write the entire stream back to either the Associated  -Contents table of the Inbox of the mail account’s delivery store (for Outlook 2010 or Outlook 2013) or to the local .nk2 file (Outlook 2007).
- Do not interact with the autocomplete stream while Outlook is running. If Outlook is running while you modify the stream, it will likely overwrite your changes when it shuts down.
- Do not write properties of type PT_MV_UNICODE and PR_MV_STRING8 into an autocomplete stream to be consumed by Microsoft Outlook 2003. These properties are only understood by Outlook 2007, Outlook 2010, and Outlook 2013.
- When developing code that interacts with Outlook 2007, we recommend that you lock the .nk2 file from modification by other processes while you are reading and writing it using standard file locking APIs (for example, LockFile in C/C++ and FileStream.Lock in C#).
- Only modify the properties of types that are from the row-set of the autocomplete stream. For more information about the autocomplete stream properties and property types, see Autocomplete Stream.

The .nk2 file format is described in depth in the [Outlook 2003/2007 NK2 File Format and Developer Guidelines](http://portalvhds6gyn3khqwmgzd.blob.core.windows.net/files/NK2/NK2WithBinaryExample.pdf) document. Also you may find the [Understanding Outlook's Auto-Complete Cache (*.NK2)](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/understanding-outlooks-autocomplete-cache-nk2/) article helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't test it before my holiday. I will test it after my holiday and then I give feedback.